# Discord Python bot that deletes messages in a certain channel which are not commands

Tags: python, discord

So I have a #support channel in which the members of my discord can type =support and the bot will message them to assist them, after that the bot will delete the  =support command that the user typed in the channel to keep the channel clean, however in this channel they can also type any message that is not a command and the bot will not delete this, is there a way for the bot to delete a message if it isn't a command?

Comment: Have you looked into [`string.startswith`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.startswith) It sounds like that's what you're looking for here

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can be done using `on_message`

```py
@bot.event
async def on_message(m):
    if m.channel.id == ChannelIDOfSupport Channel:
        if m.content.replace(bot.prefix, "") not in [i.name for i in bot.commands]:
            await m.delete()
```

Answer (score 0):

So basically what I did is replace the actual command for a message listener and if it starts with support to do the command, then I restored the commands function. It looks like this:

```
async def on_message(m):
    if m.channel.id == 735866701069025301:

        if m.content.startswith('=ticket'):

            await m.author.send('Your ticket will be created according to what you choose, use the = before choosing a number and then put the number next to it (Example: =2) \n \n **1. General Support** \n \n **2. Staff Application**')
            await m.channel.purge()

        else: {
            await m.delete()
}
    await client.process_commands(m)
```

The code below was somewhat functional however, all my @client.command or @bot.command if you want, were not functioning properly, not your fault @Poojan, I didn't paste code so you couldn't know if I was using commands instead of events.
The code above works perfectly, thank you for your help, thank you for your help too @Xetera, I followed the code and looked a bit into it and came to that conclusion :)

vvvvvvvvvvvv That answer helped me lots.